# Dijkstra Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra

I have some troubles implementing Dijkstra algorithm in Java.
I use this (first) pseudocode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
Line 15 you need to get the vertex with the lowest distance.
But how can I save the distance with the according distance.
**Note:** vertex is defined as an Integer.

My solutions that didn't work properly:

1. Map with K = vertex, V = distance, Problem: long searching to get min dist
2. SortedMap with K = distance, V = vertex, Problem: almost every distance is defined as Integer.MAX_VALUE

So I am looking for a fast way to save a vertex to a distance and it should be easy to get the vertex with min dist.

Comment: I don't think u can find something faster than Map for you solution

Comment: alternatively you could use some already implemented graph structures for java

Comment: So the best solution is actually a SortedMap with K=distance and V=List  Integer(=vertex)?

Comment: Fangio SortedMap sounds good but only problem with it will be it will not auto update the relaxed costs. Only while inserting it will put the vertex in correct order of its cost but as the cost gets relaxed then retrieving may have some issues as node retrieved may not be the one with lowest cost. So Own Min Heap should be implemented.  The problem I mentioned with SortedMap is also there in the java.util.PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a PriorityQueue. That way, you can simply remove the head, as it would have the minimum distance of all vertices.

See more information about PriorityQueue here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: Priority Queue is a bad choice for Dijkstra's algorithm, because you usually need to modify costs of vertices after each relaxation. This means you will need to find an arbitrary node  in the priority queue (which is not the head), and it cannot be done efficiently in a priority queue. It can be solved by not modifying the cost of each node, but inserting it multiple times - but that requires some more work and increases memory signature of the algorithm to `O(|E|)` (while it is usually `O(|V|)`

Comment: @amit I was having the same idea until I read here http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~rezaul/papers/TR-07-54.pdf that actually inserting and removing elements could be better than keyDecrease for most graphs.